# Problem delaying doingbackground in asyncTask !

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, thread-sleep

I have a problem using AsyncTask. I want my doing background send data to server via GET (success) BUT (Problem) when there is no connection i have to resend three time before save in my sqlite>? how can i do that ?

PS : before resend we have to let our doing background sleep(HOW?) for abit.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Threading rule for AsyncTask:

`Only once execution can be performed, any other attempt (to resume) will throw exception.` (see docs)

There you can't `sleep()` in `AsyncTask`

For that purpose you can create `BroadcastReciever` that will listen for connectivity changes.

Comment: how about wait(long mili) that allow our task wait until mili expired ??

Comment: But how you gonna resume when it says that will throw exception when you attempt to resume? I think exception will be thrown at that point.

Comment: i modify more on exception show i can resume but the point is how to wait?? :)

Comment: `try {
   this.wait(222);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
   
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
`
Try this, if you succeed to resume, share how you did. I'd really like to know..

Comment: Nikola, it's not work :'(
resume I just modify its (doing background) as recursive function

Comment: Told you so. Also you can assure yourself here 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
Threading rules says that do not call the AST methods manually...

Comment: i use wait in the exception of doing background n i got this
07-28 09:35:36.427: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12410): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()

Comment: Thx, nikola, i just found the error i have to block it by using this:

Comment: synchronized (this) {
     try {
      this.wait(3000);
     } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e1.printStackTrace();
      Log.d(tag, "wating");
     }
    }

Comment: your wait works fine unless block it using synchronized :) Thx